# Sass variable arguments syntax not working in wro4j's rubySassCss

Tags: sass, wro4j

I'm implementing Sass support in our Java application. As we already have wro4j (in the newest version 1.7.5), I decided on using it's rubySassCss as a pre-processor. I got it all configured and the whole thing process .scss files alright, until I use some of the newer syntax.

I get errors when using features that were brought in VIII 2012 with 3.2.0 version of Sass (http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html), that is variable arguments ("$args..." syntax) and block of contents in the mixin declarations.

```
@mixin mix($arg...) {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.class {
  color: black;
}
```

For example the above simple .scss file throws when processed by rubySassCss:

```
2014-06-13 11:13:48,574 DEBUG [ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter] Exception occured
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (SyntaxError) Invalid CSS after "@mixin mix($arg": expected ")", was "...) {"
        at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.support.sass.RubySassEngine.process(RubySassEngine.java:70)
        at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.RubySassCssProcessor.process(RubySassCssProcessor.java:59)
        at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:89)
        at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.LazyProcessorDecorator.process(LazyProcessorDecorator.java:49)
        at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:89)
        at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:89)
```

That wouldn't surprise me that much, if not the fact that wro4j release notes (https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/ReleaseNotes) clearly states that they implemented Sass processor 3.2.1 a long time ago in IX 2012:

> Release 1.5.0
>   Date: 27 Sep 2012
>
> (...)
>
> **Issue523    Upgrade rubySassCss processor to 3.2.1**

Anybody can tell me if they have the same problem or know what can cause it? I'd really like to take advantage of that variable arguments syntax.

---

Here's my pom.xml as well:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to force *sass-gems* to 3.2.1 version. wro4j should force that itself but it seems it didn't (it used 3.1.9 version instead). Anyway the solution is to add this anywhere in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>me.n4u.sass</groupId>
  <artifactId>sass-gems</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```